# Bootstrap 4 grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can anyone explain me about the grid system col-xs in Bootstrap 4 and is Bootstrap 4 still a alpha version? Should I start to use Bootstrap 4 in my big project works ? Will it's future updation can create any problems in my projects?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is stable. You can read about the grid here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please **[read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
[what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ***before*** asking. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-4 is stable and its latest version is `4.1.1`. Bootstrap has removed all the variants of `*-xs-*` classes. Use `col-*` for mobile.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 p-5 bg-primary">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 p-5 bg-success">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 p-5 bg-danger">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 p-5 bg-info">Column 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Aniket It is kind of you. But you do not need to thank.  It is better that you accept the answer if your doubt is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap 4 Version 4.4.0 Grid

> Grid are used to view content or page responsive on each device.  We
>   can make responsive website easily in less time for different view
>   port. Recently, I am using bootstrap 4 version 4.4.0

---

> Here, .row class is to divide a row in no. of columns you want in a
>   row.
>
> .col-* class is work on all view. But, sometime we want different look
>   at different device for any particular content. Then, we have to use
>   the following classes which we can use identically for all individual
>   device.
>
> .col-xl-* class is used for extra large device like big TV and
>   Desktop.
>
> .col-lg-* class is used for laptop, ipad pro, normal desktop.
>
> .col-md-* class is used for medium devices like ipad.
>
> .col-sm-* class is used for small device like: Galaxy, iphone 6/7/8
>   plus.
>
> .col-xs-* class is used for extra small device like: iphone 5/6.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Home</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Products</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Home</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Products</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Home</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Products</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Home</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Products</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Home</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Products</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Home</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Products</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
```